# restAPI storing fridge temperatures needs to send values continously

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a restAPI in .NET(C#) to store and retrieve fridge temperatures. 
Every fridge sends its temperature once per second to the API and the value is stored in a mySQL database. The users need to be able to retrieve the temperatures over a period of time to make a live graphic. 
If I needed to retrieve a temperature once, I would do a GET request and have my get function return just the current value but how can I keep that connection "alive"? 
Also, the users and the fridges should identify themselves when connecting to the API, is it best username and pwd or token identification?

Comment: I would advice to include some code of what you have tried into your question. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: To connect, it is preferable to use an oauth 2.0 authentication type. Instead of maintaining the connection, it is better if the device makes a request to the server each x time